# Parsing data from jQuery in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm getting closer.  I have a form that want to submit to a PHP file for processing and updating a MySQL db and then update a div.  I can send the data to my PHP file and see it but not sure how to access it so it is useful.

from my JS

```
var str = $("form").serialize();
xmlhttp.open("GET","concessions_write.php?"+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

sends this to my PHP file

```
concessions_write.php?btn%5B%5D=button01&itm%5B%5D=Hot+Dog&prc%5B%5D=1.00&id%5B%5D=1&btn%5B%5D=button02&itm%5B%5D=Popcorn&prc%5B%5D=1.00&id%5B%5D=3&btn%5B%5D=button03&itm%5B%5D=Combo&prc%5B%5D=3.50&id%5B%5D=2&btn%5B%5D=button04&itm%5B%5D=Nabs&prc%5B%5D=0.50&id%5B%5D=4&name=&message=
```

in my PHP file a

```
print_r($_GET);
```

gives

```
Array (
    [btn] => Array (
        [0] => button01
        [1] => button02
        [2] => button03
        [3] => button04 
    )
    [itm] => Array (
        [0] => Hot Dog
        [1] => Popcorn
        [2] => Combo
        [3] => Nabs
    )
    [prc] => Array (
        [0] => 1.00
        [1] => 1.00
        [2] => 3.50
        [3] => 0.50
    )
    [id] => Array (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 4
    )
    [name] =>
    [message] =>
)
```

This is the info I need.  Each entry has 4 parts - `btn`, `itm`, `prc` and `id` and I currently have 4 entries.  Just not sure how to break it down to usable arrays so I can write the data back to the db.

Look at `parse_str` but can't seem to get it to work.

Ideas?  Also any idea where name and message might be coming from?  No form elements with this.

Comment: This question is vague. You have your request, and you know how to get your data from it, and now you want... what?

Comment: Why are you creating an `XMLHttpRequest` manually? The jQuery `$.get()` function would make this simpler.

Comment: Related to OP's previous questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845765/getting-variable-size-form-to-javascript-and-php-ajax), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974462/passing-variable-sized-form) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045381/passing-variable-sized-form-using-jquery-to-php-file-for-processing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know the format of the data you can do this after you collect the $_GET as array():

```
$_GET['btn']['0'];
```

The name and meesage have to be coming form form input names.

Comment: Thanks.  As the length is variable is there an easy way to get the length of the array?

Comment: Use `count` or `sizeof`. Basically the same. `$length = sizeof($_GET['btn']);`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you just need a `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $btn = $_GET['btn'][$i];
    $itm = $_GET['itm'][$i];
    $prc = $_GET['prc'][$i];
    $id = $_GET['id'][$i];

    // Sanitise and save these values here
}
```